# PagerTabStrip with all captial letters

Tags: android, pagertabstrip

I have a PagerTabStrip in my app and I put in Strings to the Tab,

```
titles = new String[]{
            "Tab1",
            "Tab2",
            "Tab3"

};
```

so suppose only "T" here is capital, but I get all capital letters.

I also tried to fix this by adding textAllCap to be false through the style in xml:

```
 <style name="viewPagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/LightGrey2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
 </style>
```

and then apply it in the layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainFragContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/titleStrip"
        style="@style/viewPagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/LightGrey"
        />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

But they still appear to be all cap, i.e. "TAB1" , "TAB2", "TAB3"

Can anyone help?

Comment: this is not a duplicate of post.. because I'm working on PagerTabStrip  but not TabLayout.. and to my understanding, the answer suggested in that post doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

Comment: I tried to put it in   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip/>..but it is still not working..